# Teradata - what index strategy is best?

Tags: sql, teradata

For example, I have to create a table with following fields:

```
client_id (num) 
local_id (num)
unit_id (char)
category (char)
first_product_date (date)
```

`client_id` is unique. All fields will be used in joins, WHERE etc.
Please explain, which way to use indexes is best and why?

1) Primary unique + others in secondary

```
PRIMARY UNIQUE INDEX (client_dk)
SECONDARY INDEX (local_id, unit_id, category, first_product_date)
```

2) Primary non unique + others in secondary

```
PRIMARY INDEX (client_dk)
SECONDARY INDEX (local_id, unit_id, category, first_product_date)
```

3) All in primary

```
PRIMARY INDEX (client_dk, local_id, unit_id, category, first_product_date)
```

4) Secondary unique + others in primary

```
PRIMARY INDEX (local_id, unit_id, category, first_product_date)
SECONDARY UNIQUE INDEX (client_dk)
```

5) Any other way?

Thx!

Comment: Indexes should be designed around queries and data models, not around tables in isolation.

Comment: ok, so could you describe your conception?

Comment: _Columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Start with a Primary Index only ` UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX (client_dk)`, Secondary Indexes are hardly needed in Teradata.

Comment: Gordon is right, indexes should be designed around whole data model while keeping in mind the access patterns on it. Also in most cases you don't need Secondary Indexes, it's too much efforts in terms of DB resources and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes for TD indexes:

Your primary index is the most important one -- pick it based on:

1) Access - how do you access data from the table
2) Distribution - how unique is the data --> PI value hash is used to store/locate rows
3) Volatility - how often do the PI values change --> reduce data relocation

Ideally, you want a unique index, but it really depends on how plan to access the data.  Having a non-unique index is not necessarily bad.

To target specific problem queries and tables, you can try:

1) Using DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION to see recommended statistics for specific queries.  Run an EXPLAIN on your query and you'll get some stat collection ideas.

2) Playing with join Indexes.

3) Like mentioned earlier, secondary indexes are not always very useful.  So don't go creating them all over the place.

And like the folks before said, figure out how all the tables relate to each other and the type of questions you plan to ask of your data.  That will dictate your index choices.